# Connect domain to a page on another website

Tags: dns

We have built an online platform which allows businesses to sign up and show off their services, along with having a shop on that platform.
Currently, the url for a business profile would be something like:

```
example.com/businesses/132/some-company
```

...and the shop:

```
example.com/businesses/132/some-company/shop
```

Now, to make the business profiles more appealing to companies, I was wondering whether it would be possible to connect a domain to that page on our platform, so that the url could instead simply be:

```
some-company.com
```

...ideally with subpaths:

```
some-company.com/shop
```

...which points to above url.
I would NOT like to redirect, because that would remove the custom domain from the url bar in the browser.

As a frontend developer, I imagine this like having a full-screen iframe pointing to the business profile url on the custom domain. But this approach would require development per business on our platform, which might not be necessary, if there was a better solution.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reverse proxy engine like NGINX to accomplish this cleanly.

Here's a rough sample of what the some-company.conf may end up looking like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.some-company.com some-company.com;

    location /shop/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com/businesses/132/some-company/shop/;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;        
    }
}
```

There are additional setting needed for SSL and other re-write options but this should get you rolling in that direction.

Comment: So I just got to try it out. I was able to connect `some-company.com` to `example.com`. However, it's an SPA (react.js) and always redirects me to `/`, instead of `/businesses/132/some-company/shop/`... Any idea why or what I need to change?

Comment: you can use "location / {" instead of "location /shop/ {" so nginx can point everything relative to the "/" over including "/","/shop/","/shop/checkout/", "/support/", etc .   you can create multiple "location" directives as well if you need to do something different with a specific sub-path.

Comment: Hmm yeah I figured that an tried it, but it always took me back to `/`. Doing `some-company.com/shop` showed a 404, because there's no `example.com/shop`, only nested in that `/businesses/132/some-company/shop/` path...

Comment: Try an extra "location = / {" for it to pick up the slash and nonslash sub-paths (note the equal sign).   You'll still need "location / {" to pick up the domain only match.

Comment: The other technique that is common is to have the directive without the slash "/shop" and have a rewrite near the server directive to remove any trailing slashes as it comes in "rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;":

Comment: Can I share with you what I've tried? Because I've put that `location = / {` part but it doesn't work. If you'd look at the file, maybe you'll see anything obvious that I don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203115/discussion-between-linusgeffarth-and-viet-hoang).